# Tomcat running on linux server. Can't get response while making request from this server, but can while making remote requests

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, url, server

I have linux server and installed `Tomcat 8` on it. I have deployed 2 wars and one war should make some requests to other, but I always get :

```
Failed to connect to ... Connection refused
```

I can easily make requests from remote sources, but can't get response, while making requests from the same server.

I also tried make requests on url of this server, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` and different ports `443, 8080, 80`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: On the server you're having trouble, try connecting to the public-facing IP address instead of 127.0.0.1.  If that works, then I'm wondering if tomcat is only bound to that interface, and not localhost.  You might want to check your conf/server.xml file, and take a look at your Connector and see if it is specifically binding to a specific IP address.  If it is, then that's why...

Answer (score 0):

1-check your code.

if you cannot see your project in browser{
    2-check tomcat is running.
}

3-check firewall is not running.

Comment: Both war files can be accessible from the browser and is working now. In code I'm getting the same error. How can I check or shut down the firewall on debian?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that tomcat is already running on port so try to stop it from terminal:

```
sudo  service tomcat7 stop
```

then start again